# Sparklyr/Spark NLP connect via YARN

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, sparkr, sparklyr

I'm new to sparklyr and spark nlp. Had gotten a local connection running no problem and test data was saving and being read back etc. Today when I loaded the real data which is a batch of text data the errors began. From other discussions it appeared to be caused by attempting to connect via a yarn hive even though I had it set to local.  I've tried various configs and reset paths to spark in my terminal etc. Now I can't get a local connection.

It appears spark should be residing in usr/lib/spark. But it is not. It is in Users/user_name/spark. I've installed apache at the command line and it resides in the usr/lib/ but under 'apache spark' so not being referenced.

1. Running Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME") in R Studio still shows 'Users/user_name/spark' as location.
2. Resetting SPARK_HOME location via R

```
home <- "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", spark_home = home, version = "3.3.0")
```

returns the following error:

```
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  : 
  Failed to find 'spark2-submit' or 'spark-submit' under '/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark', please verify SPARK_HOME.
```

3. Setting SPARK_HOME to where it originally installed in my Users folder is not changing this error.

I don't know am I supposed to install some dependencies to enable YARN Hives or what to do? I've tried these configs:

```
conf <- spark_config()

conf$spark.driver.cores <- 2
conf$spark.driver.memory <- "3G"
conf$spark.executor.cores <- 2
conf$spark.executor.memory <- "3G"
conf$spark.executor.instances <- 5
#conf$sparklyr.log.console <- TRUE
conf$sparklyr.verbose <- TRUE

sc <- spark_connect(
  master = "yarn",
  version = "2.4.3",
  config = conf,
  spark_home = "usr/lib/spark"
)
```

changing spark_home back and forth. Get this error eitherway:

```
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  : 
  SPARK_HOME directory 'usr/lib/spark' not found
```

Is there an interaction between a terminal desktop install of apache_spark and the spark_install() through R?

Why did it not allow me to continue working locally or would text data require a hive?

```
spark_home <- spark_home_dir()
```

returns nothing! I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the R environment variable to `SPARK_HOME`, runing the following in an R session:
`Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = /path/where/you/installed/spark)`